# Excel VBA: How to return in-range location with Range.Find?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA when using the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) the output is the address of the found cell relative to the sheet (ie: SomeSheet.Range("C3")). Is there a way to return the position of the found cell within the range being searched? (ie: SearchedRange.Cells(2,4))

I am presently handling this with the snippet below but was wondering if there is a built in method or property that will handle this.

```
RowInRange = SomeRange.Find("foo").Row - (SomeRange.Row - 1)
```

Comment: Well, you know the range being searched, you know the found range relative to the sheet. Do you need it spelled out? Do the math.

Comment: I don't know the range.

Comment: @MechanizedMedic then how can you know where the cell is relative?  If you do not know the starting point, by which reference do you want the relative location?  And if you do not know the starting point any is as good as the next.  I would explain more in your original post using [edit] what you are trying to accomplish, show us what you start with and what you want to achieve, and any attempts you have made to do what you want.

Comment: FWIW - `Range.Find` doesn't return an address - it returns a `Range` object.  (I assume you must have used the `.Address` property of the range that was returned.)

Comment: @YowE3K, I just updated my question to be specific to my case. This isn't really about solving an immediate problem; more just trying to revise my code and learn new stuff.

Comment: @MechanizedMedic - You **do** know the range. `SomeRange` (as defined in whatever code you have). And the starting point of `SomeRange` is `SomeRange.Cells(1,1)` - which is top left most cell in starting range. The rest is just math, with the caveat that non-contiguous ranges may not be as simple.

Comment: Argh - I was about to post an answer and someone interrupted me with a work-related question.  (Don't they know I only come to work so that I can answer SO questions without my family interrupting me?!?!?)  So, an hour later, I just pressed "Save" on my "answer" and now I see you have already been using the same method.

Comment: So, there is an easy way of finding the sheet address of a cell using an address relative to another sheet address (i.e. `Worksheets(1).Range("D4").Range("B3")` is equivalent to `Worksheets(1).Range("E6")`) but starting from "D4" and "E6" and trying to get "B3" (or "row 3, column 2") requires subtractions of some sort.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, there's more than one way to set a range. In my case this table moves around due to my coworkers adding and removing columns and or rows of annotations. I named the table and they don't fool with that so I can set my range with 
`Set SomeRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("MovingTable")` ...Does this explain why I don't know the range as you presumed?

Comment: If you know that you are using the range `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("MovingTable")` then you know the range you are using.  (It's address is `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("MovingTable").Address`, it starts on row `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("MovingTable").Row` and it starts in column `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("MovingTable").Column`, it's first cell is `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("MovingTable").Cells(1, 1)`, etc.)  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is just simple maths to get the answer:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim SearchedRange As Range
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Dim RelativeRangeAddress As String

    Range("E15").Value = "ABC"            ' Dummy some data

    Set SearchedRange = Range("D5:G123")  ' Dummy search area
    Set FoundRange = SearchedRange.Find(What:="ABC")

    'Find address relative to start of search range
    RelativeRangeAddress = FoundRange.Offset(1 - SearchedRange.Row, _
                                             1 - SearchedRange.Column).Address        
    MsgBox RelativeRangeAddress & " is " & _
           SearchedRange.Range(RelativeRangeAddress).Value ' will display "$B$11 is ABC"

    'To just find the row and column (which is probably easier)
    MsgBox "Relative row is " & FoundRange.Row - SearchedRange.Row + 1
    MsgBox "Relative column is " & FoundRange.Column - SearchedRange.Column + 1
End Sub
```